# Cryptfs : Unexpected value for crypto key location

Tags: encryption, lineageos, disk-encryption

```
Phone: Samsung S9 Plus, 256Gb
OS: Lineage OS 17.1 (Android 10)
ROOT: TWRP 3.5
```

I installed Lineage OS 17.1 on a Samsung S9+. It's been working fine so far. However, when I encrypt the OS from the security menu, right after the screen goes black with the green android-like logo, the phone quickly reboots back to the non encrypted OS. Going again through the process does not help.

logcat shows:

```
--------- beginning of main
01-20 19:17:52.959 4019 4129 D vold : fdeEnable(3, *, 0)
01-20 19:17:52.960 4019 4129 D vold : !fscrypt_is_native, spawning fdeEnableInternal
01-20 19:17:52.960 4019 403 E Cryptfs : Unexpected value for crypto key location
01-20 19:17:52.961 4019 403 E Cryptfs : Cannot get size of block device
01-20 19:17:53.067 4019 403 W vold : Found symlink /proc/29802/cwd referencing /data/misc/keystore
01-20 19:17:53.067 4019 403 W vold : Found symlink /proc/29803/fd/7 referencing /data/vendor/gps/.lhd.lock
01-20 19:17:53.068 4019 403 W vold : Found symlink /proc/29803/fd/12 referencing /data/vendor/gps/.pipe.gpsd_to_lhd.to_server
01-20 19:17:53.068 4019 403 W vold : Found symlink /proc/29803/fd/14 referencing /data/vendor/gps/.pipe.gpsd_to_lhd.to_client
01-20 19:17:53.069 4019 403 W vold : Found symlink /proc/29804/fd/7 referencing /data/vendor/gps/.gpsd.lock
...
...
01-20 19:17:53.217 4019 403 W vold : Sending Killed to 32740
01-20 19:17:53.218 4019 403 W vold : Sending Killed to 32509
01-20 19:17:53.218 4019 403 W vold : Sending Killed to 32383
...
...
01-20 19:17:53.221 4019 403 E Cryptfs : Unexpected value for crypto key location
01-20 19:17:53.221 4019 403 E Cryptfs : Cannot get size of block device
--------- beginning of crash
```

I tried the steps given [here](https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/-/issues/1027#note_204774424) on /data (/dev/block/sda25), but it did not do it for me either.

1. Any idea on how I can debug further `Cryptfs : Unexpected value for crypto key location`?
2. Is there a way to encrypt /data via the command line if this keeps failing?

Comment: Just for clarification: The OS is never encrypted, just the data on the user data partition is encrypted (should be FBE - File-Based Encryption if I am not mistaken).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this device is encrypted with FDE full-disk-encryption. depending on how you installed Magisk the `forceencrypt=` flag is gone. that's what the *"crypto key location"* refer. edit your **fstab** and restore `encryptable=` flag that might help to use Samsung encryption in boot mode. but TWRP is most likely not able to decrypt anyway, so there is no benefit of having TWRP

btw this is a well known Magisk Bug and topjohnwu decided to ignore my fix

Comment: Thanks @alecxs, Magisk was installed throught TWRP, after LineageOS. /system/etc/fstab only has reference to the swap at this point. From what you're saying, encrypting book doesn't make much sense, is that right? Lastly, for learning purposes, how can I verify for myself that the device is encrypted with FDE?

Comment: afaik the file should located */vendor/etc/fstab.\** should be something like */dev/block/platform/11120000.ufs/by-name/USERDATA /data ext4 wait,check,encryptable=footer* and you can check with *getprop ro.crypto.type*

Comment: I had the wrong fstab... This is the vendor one: https://pastebin.com/raw/nimAc6vr, FYI.

Comment: you can just add the missing flag. when dealing with system files make sure to preserve owner+ permissions+ secontext (`ls -lnZ`) and keep correct line ending `LF` (not `CRLF`)

Comment: I see. `getprop ro.crypto.type` returns nil, and `getprop | grep crypto` returns: 
 `[ro.crypto.fuse_sdcard]: [true]`, `[ro.crypto.state]: [unsupported]`, and `[ro.security.fips_scrypto.ver]: [2.2]`

Comment: It does not look encrypted from the looks of it.

Comment: I've replaced `=footer` with `encypted=footer` in the `fstab` for `USERDATA`. Now, `getprop | grep crypto` returns: `[ro.crypto.fuse_sdcard]: [true]`, `[ro.crypto.state]: [unencrypted]`, `[ro.security.fips_scrypto.ver]: [2.2]`, `[vold.encrypt_progress]: [error_not_encrypted]`. Am I on the right track here...? Should I run the encryption manually or something?

Comment: [encryptable=](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/fs_mgr/fs_mgr_fstab.cpp#186) is the proper flag (not *encrypted=*) and you must encrypt from security menu afterwards. if still not working follow your link to free space for crypto-footer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118763/discussion-between-adriano-lucas-and-alecxs).