# Is a nandroid backup possible with encrypted /data?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, nandroid

Years ago, I was able to make nandroids using CWM Recovery or TWRP. Is that possible on more modern versions of Android which encrypt /data by default?

Comment: Yes if your recovery supports decryption.

Comment: TWRP definitely supports full nandroid backup provided that user specific data for ALL users is decrypted (it asks for primay user's credentials during recovery boot).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clean LineageOS 17.1 install and empty device - can't work out how to mount data partition in TWRP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233129/clean-lineageos-17-1-install-and-empty-device-cant-work-out-how-to-mount-data)