# Samsung boot loop after flashing patched Magisk image

Tags: samsung, rooting, boot-loop, unbricking

My phone keeps showing both the Samsung logos while booting. It also shows the unlocked boot loader screen. I tried flashing the stock boot.img but it only removes the red text when booting. After some time it show a screen that looks like the stock recovery and shows this text:

Try again
Factory data reset
View recovery logs

I tried to do the data reset but that did not fix anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cryptfs : Unexpected value for crypto key location](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233093/cryptfs-unexpected-value-for-crypto-key-location)

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have patched the **whole** rom *AP_[device_model_sw_ver].tar.md5* (not only *boot.img*) according to [install instructions](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#instructions) (to avoid discrepancies in several fstabs), start from scratch again.

this time try *preserve force encryption* in Magisk settings to avoid issues with encryption. after factory reset userdata encryption should work again.

Of course as always don't forget to deactivate [VaultKeeper](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#unlocking-bootloader) before flashing custom binaries

Comment: Also I use Debian Linux so is there a  a method using Heimdall. I also tried Jodin but it just ask to get the pit file and when I press "yes" it Grey's out the start button.