# Does Android Lolipop 5.1 get encrypted by itself upon first boot?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, security, encryption, 5.1-lollipop, disk-encryption

My doubts are,

1. Would an android device shipped with Lollipop 5.0 get encrypted itself upon first boot? I saw a lot of blogs saying [Lolipop does not come with default encryption](https://gizmodo.com/android-5-0-devices-arent-encrypted-by-default-despite-1689097752) but in the official link it says that [devices get encrypted by default upon first boot](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk) — too many confusing blog articles. What is the difference between default encryption and encryption on first boot?
2. Most blogs say we have to manually encrypt the Device but I don't understand — if it's already encrypted upon first boot, then why encrypt again manually? What is the advantage?

Comment: As far as I remember Google had introduced automatic encryption with Android 5 and applied it in the Nexus phones. But nearly no other manufacturer had taken over the encryption feature at that time. Therefore most likely your phone is not encrypted. You can check that in Android settings -> Security if encryption is enabled. If it is enabled you should also see on every reboot the pre-boot password entering dialog asking for the device password.

Comment: @Robert official documentation says " **Upon first boot, the device creates a randomly generated 128-bit master key and then hashes it with a default password and stored salt. The default password is: "default_password" However, the resultant hash is also signed through a TEE (such as TrustZone), which uses a hash of the signature to encrypt the master key."**

Comment: The documentation may state that but only if that feature is mandatory for Google Android all phones had it implementad. For example a CPU with TEE was AFAIK not a requirement at that time so most manufactures were using a CPU without. That contradicts your documentation - what now?

Comment: @Robert thanks man.Understood

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Tab A 9.7 LTE SM-T555 (shipped with Android 5) latest stock ROM (Android 7) still unencrypted (I own) - it really depends on how accurate OEMs maintain it. *1. What is the difference between default encryption and encryption on first boot?* - nothing. *2. why encrypt again manually?* - secure start-up

Comment: if device does not boot, for further analysis download stock ROM (off device or www) and have a look in [fstab](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233093/cryptfs-unexpected-value-for-crypto-key-location/233095#comment308223_233095) (or just mention your device model so we can maybe help out)